# jacoco4sbt is not "detecting" my tests. Any idea why?

Tags: scala, sbt, specs2, jacoco

I have a typical sbt (0.13) build and have added the jacoco4sbt plugin to my build.

```
addSbtPlugin("de.johoop" % "jacoco4sbt" % "2.1.1")
```

I use specs2 to run my tests (2.2.2).

If I run

```
~>sbt
>test
```

all my tests get run (120 of them). However, if I do

```
>jacoco:test
```

it runs 0 tests, as if the jacoco configuration cannot find them.

A quick search reveals that there is an issue with jacoco4sbt and Play because Play sets parallelExecution to false. However, I am not using Play, and parallelExecution is set to True for both configurations. I have tried to set them both to false to no avail.

Any idea what might be going wrong?

n.b. The project I am working on is open source, so I created a branch where I put my attempt at adding jacoco4sbt. Feel free to clone it and see what is happening for yourself.

https://github.com/jedesah/scala-codesheet-api/tree/jacoco

Comment: Do you have `fork in test := true` by any chance?

Comment: Certainly not explicitly. But I can try forcing it to false and see what happens. Let me get back to you on what comes of it.

Comment: Tried setting it explicitly to false, but to no avail. Still no tests are being executed by the jacoco:cover or jacoco:test tasks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this issue, but upgraded to Specs2 2.2.3 and jacoco4sbt started producing output from that point.

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, I had the same problem when using specs2. When I switched to ScalaTest, jacoco4sbt started detecting my tests.

I have a very basic configuration too, so I don't know we're missing something or if there's something wrong in the current jacoco4sbt version. I did try version 2.1.0 of jacoco4sbt but had the same results.